# nginx + uWsgi is not using it's maximum capability. 90% workers remain idle all the time

Tags: nginx, deployment, django, uwsgi

I have deployed my Django application using nginx + uwsgi. I have also implemented micro caching and made other changes by following this article ([Nginx 10k concurrent connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/652180/nginx-10k-concurrent-connections)).

Now I am using jMeter and testing for 1000 concurrent requests. Earlier, the server used to throw 502 after 70-80 requests but currently it's serving all 1000 requests with out fail.

Problems are:

1. The average response time is 18 secs. It starts with 1.9 secs and goes to 18.
2. I am using 8 core server and server load never reaches even 20%.
   [htop screenshot during load test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy6ar.png)
3. uwsgitop shows that 13 uwsgi workers remains in idle state. only 2-3 workers are serving all 1000 requests.
   [uwsgihtop screenshot during load test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y745R.png)

Why nginx / uwsgi is not using server's maximum capacity to serve requests. How can I make server to use all uwsgi workers so that I can reduce my response time from 18 sec to 1-2 secs.