# Changing ulimit on systemd

Tags: ulimit

I've found [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/628610/increasing-nproc-for-processes-launched-by-systemd-on-centos-7), showing how to change the ulimits on systemd.

```
/etc/systemd/system/<servicename>.d/override.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=49152
```

I found a [website](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-03-26-increase-open-files-limit) suggesting to change the ulimits for systemd in these files:

```
/etc/systemd/system.conf
/etc/systemd/user.conf

[Manager] 
DefaultLimitNOFILE=49152
```

- What's the difference between this two methods?
- What's best practive?

Thanks for input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/systemd/[system|user].conf` are used to define *default* values for service unit files.

As I suppose that you only want to change settings for a single unit file, the `/etc/systemd/system/<servicename>.d/override.conf` is the cleanest method, and definitively a best practice.

Comment: Do you know any way of defining the limits of a specific systemctl service run by a user (--user) ?